# How to user dotnet identity usermanager and signinmanager with custom / default authentication scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-identity

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API setup with a default auth scheme like this:

```cs
const string CookieScheme = "cookie";

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyCustom.Identity";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    });
```

In controllers, I'm trying to use signin manager and user manager for more control in the flow such as, logging user in on registration etc...

Here's the `AuthController` with registration endpoint:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/auth")]
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;

    public AuthController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        ILogger<AuthController> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("register")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
    {
        var user = new IdentityUser
        {
            UserName = model.Email,
            Email = model.Email
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

        if (!result.Succeeded)
        {
            return BadRequest(result.Errors);
        }

        await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, true);

        var responseData = new
        {
            status = "success",
            message = "Registered successfully!",
            user = new
            {
                username = user.UserName,
                email = user.Email,
                id = user.Id
            }
        };

        return Ok(responseData);
    }
}
```

But this code doesn't use the "cookie" scheme (the cookie that is set has different name ".AspDotnet.Identity" which is default scheme).

This is causing more trouble when I access routes that require authentication, such as:

```
[Authorize]
[HttpGet]
[Route("user")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUser()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        return Unauthorized("Not authorized to perform this action");
    }

    var responseData = new
    {
        status = "success",
        user = new
        {
            username = user.UserName,
            email = user.Email,
            id = user.Id
        }
    };

    return Ok(responseData);
}
```

How to properly setup .NET Core Identity and controller routes with more control overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the asp.net identity default cookie options by following.

```
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
        options.Cookie.Name = "MyCustom.Identity";
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;

});
```

Comment: is it possible to make the signin manager use default authentication scheme ? I kinda found a way by using `_signInManager.AuthenticationScheme = Constants.CookieScheme;` but looking for a global solution. I'm new to dotnet, and finding my way around these

Comment: @AdharshM but signInManager is for "asp.net identity" which is `IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme`.     "CookieScheme" is a standalone cookie scheme which should be sign in use `httpcontext.signinasync(...)".  Does signInManger really work for cookiescheme?

Comment: when I use `_signInManager.AuthenticationScheme = "cookie";` everywhere I use signinManager It's working as expected with configured AddCookie("cookie") scheme. I also tried httpcontext.signInAsync with claims principal and it works well. I thought signinmanager is an abstraction on top of httpctx and it chooses default scheme. anyway still not sure how to force default scheme for _signInManager globally.

Comment: @AdharshM I also couldn't find a global setting for this.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something like this:

In my program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.RequireAdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.Admin));
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.RequireStandartRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.Standart));
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.RequireCorporateAdminRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.CorporateAdmin));
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.RequireCorporateRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.Corporate));
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.RequireEnterpriseRole, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.Enterprise));
    options.AddPolicy(PolicyName.ElevatedRights, policy => policy.RequireRole(RoleName.CorporateAdmin, RoleName.Corporate));
});
```

These policy names are just simple string consts:

```
public class PolicyName : PolicyNameGlobal
{
    public const string RequireCorporateAdminRole = "RequireCorporateAdminRole";
    public const string RequireCorporateRole = "RequireCorporateRole";
    public const string RequireEnterpriseRole = "RequireEnterpriseRole";
    public const string ElevatedRights = "ElevatedRights";
}
```

In my login.cshtml.cs on post if the user is valid and password is OK:

```
    // set default claims
    var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Username),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name),
            new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.UserId, user._id.ToString())
        };

    // set user role claims
    foreach (var roleName in user.Roles)
    {
        Claim roleClaim = new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName);
        claims.Add(roleClaim);
    }

    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
        claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(120),
        // The time at which the authentication ticket expires. A 
        // value set here overrides the ExpireTimeSpan option of 
        // CookieAuthenticationOptions set with AddCookie.

        IsPersistent = Input.RememberMe,
        // Whether the authentication session is persisted across 
        // multiple requests. Required when setting the 
        // ExpireTimeSpan option of CookieAuthenticationOptions 
        // set with AddCookie. Also required when setting 
        // ExpiresUtc.

        IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow,
        // The time at which the authentication ticket was issued.

        //RedirectUri = <string>
        // The full path or absolute URI to be used as an http 
        // redirect response value.
    };

    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
        CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
        new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
        authProperties);
```

As you might see I am adding role claims. And using these role claims to restrict pages.

```
[Authorize(Policy = PolicyName.RequireAdminRole)]
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
```

You may use more that one role policy if you need.
Hope this helps.

Comment: So far from my exploration, I think I should use httpcontext.signinasync method for more convenience.

Comment: Mate, it is not so different for the Web API, from your auth end point you are returning a JWT and send in the header for the protected endpoints.

I suggest you the check these search results:
https://www.google.com/search?q=jwt+authentication+in+web+api

Comment: I Just wanted to use `signInManager.SignInAsync`, it wasn't working out and ended up using `HttpContext.SignInAsync` that's all.

Comment: OK, happy to hear that helped.